# Find by two nested properties in the same property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have two documents called `Book` and `Shop`. In the `Book` document I have a `list` of `AvailabilityForShop` objects with `shopId` and `AvailabilityForShopStatus`.

In this list I'm putting what are the shops this book can be bought and later I can make available or unavailable if books are out of the stock in relevant shops

Dtos,

```
class Book {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolen active;
    .....
    private List<AvailabilityForShop> availabilityForShops;
}

class AvailabilityForShop {
    private String shopId;
    private AvailabilityForShopStatus availabilityForShopStatus;
}

enum AvailabilityForShopStatus{
    AVAILABLE, UNAVAILABLE
}
```

Now I want to get the all the available books for a shop. I have added a query like following,

```
@RestResource(path = "availableBooksForShop")
@Query("{'$and': [{'active': 'true'}, {'availabilityForShops.shopId' : ?0}]}")
Page<Book> findAvailableBooksForShop(String shopId);
```

This is the query I have came up with. But it will returns the books matching only `shopId` and without considering the `availabilityForShopStatus` for that matching value. How can I get the books that match `shopId` and availability of that shop is `AVAILABLE`?

Comment: Do you use `@DBRef` on `availabilityForShops`?

Comment: you are not using ```availabilityForShopStatus``` inside query, that's why only shopId filter is applied, add it to get results you want.

Comment: You can use elemMatch also. It will be better for your use case. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/